# How can we find the pole of square root function?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

What is the pole of the following function
$$f(z)=\frac{\pi}{1+\sqrt{z}}, \quad z\in C$$

Comment: How are you defining $\sqrt z$? There isn't a single standard definition of it as a function on the complex numbers.

Comment: @MattSamuel I've usually seen the default being where one uses the principal branch of log to denote complex powers without any other considerations. This notation is especially common with the "principal" roots (square root, cube root, etc). But I think I do see your point - using the principal branch would only ever give us functions with positive real part, so this function would have no poles.

Comment: What have you tried? As it stands, this is a bit of a low effort question. Please edit the post with your attempts, concerns, or larger context for why you would want such a thing.

Comment: As indicated above, this will depend on the definition of the square root. If $\sqrt z$ is defined to be analytic in a neighborhood of $z = 1$ with $\sqrt 1 = -1$, then $f(z)$ will have a simple pole at $z = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$1+\sqrt z=0\implies z=(-1)^2=1.$$

But with the usual convention, $\sqrt1+1\ne0$, so there is no pole.

Comment: Thank you so much. can we say that zero is a pole ? for $$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt(z)}$$?

Comment: @Momo: nope, a pole has an integer exponent.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "pole", but there is a "branch point" at $z=0$. Looking at the monodromy of the function around $z=0$, we see that the values change as $\sqrt{z}$ changes by $-1$. It doesn't "blow up" at $z=0$...

Comment: Thank you so much.